# How to use DependentTransaction with EF 4.1 DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, transactionscope

How can we use DependentTransaction with EntityFramework 4.1? If you see the article "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858750/what-is-the-reason-of-transaction-context-in-use-by-another-session" to bring transaction into another thread we have to open the connection first but EF 4.1 gives error if connection is opened. Any idea how to do that ?