# Using transaction with SQL Server Linked Server - Transaction context in use by another session

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In one StoredProcedure, I am using a linked server to do some inserts/updates in another DB. Have wrapped the code in a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [mySchema].[mySP] (paramList)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

    DECLARE @TranStarted AS BIT = 0;

    BEGIN TRY
            IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
              BEGIN TRANSACTION;
              SET @TranStarted = 1;
            END 

   -- Do some stuff with linked server (inserts and updates on another server)

   IF @TranStarted = 1
      BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
      END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @TranStarted = 1
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END

        PRINT 'ERROR_NUMBER: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR(10));
        PRINT 'ERROR_MESSAGE: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        PRINT 'ERROR_SEVERITY: ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS NVARCHAR(2));
        PRINT 'ERROR_STATE: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS NVARCHAR(3));
        PRINT 'ERROR_PROCEDURE: ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        PRINT 'ERROR_LINE: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(5));
    END CATCH           
END
```

And here is the result:

```
ERROR_NUMBER: 3910
ERROR_MESSAGE: Transaction context in use by another session.
ERROR_SEVERITY: 16
ERROR_STATE: 2

ERROR_LINE: 1
```

I've seen this:
[Related track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704553/transaction-context-in-use-by-another-session) but I think I don't have any loopback linked servers

**The StoredProcedure works fine without transaction block**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

This might not fit your scenario, but just in case it does fit your's or someone else's...

I encountered the "Transaction context is in use..." error when updating a table with a trigger referencing a linked server that is on the same SQL server and the connection string included `";MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`.  The application I was adding script to needed that functionality.

If, however, I use a connection string without `MultipleActiveResultSets`, the application was able to successfully update the table.  In our PROD environment, the linked server is connecting to a different server, but in our DEV environment, it links back to the same server.  With `MultipleActiveResultSets` set to true, SQL server would attempt to create a distributed transaction and fail because it is a loopback (which many posts have indicated is not supported by DTC).

With MultipleActiveResultSets set to false (or left out of the connection string), SQL server does not have a problem with the loopback.